# How to stop model from predicting probabilities?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I have created a model that is meant to predict when a curve has reached a maximum/minimum. However, this model is also meant to predict whether the curve is not at a maximum or a minimum.

To do this I labeled my dataset with another column that indicates, "1" if the curve has reached a minimum, "2" if the curve has reached a maximum, and "0" if the curve is not at a maximum or a minimum. I used the savgol_filter from scipy.signal to smooth the data so that the noisy maximums and minimums could be ignored.

The real issue comes during training. Instead, the model predicts probabilities of 0, 1, and 2 based on the number of these in the dataset. It results in a constant spread in the predictions of all three columns, with no actual prediction occurring. The training loss does not improve either.

**Example of what the predictions look like:**

```
predictions1 = model1.predict(trainX)
i = 0
while (i < len(predictions1)):
    print(f'{predictions1[i]} - {trainY[i]}')
    i+=1

[0.3735279  0.3069231  0.31954893] - 2.0
[0.37347972 0.30695325 0.319567  ] - 0.0
[0.37339583 0.3070028  0.31960133] - 0.0
[0.3732677  0.30707628 0.31965607] - 1.0
[0.3731317  0.30715463 0.31971365] - 2.0
[0.37299597 0.30723253 0.31977156] - 0.0
[0.37281436 0.3073345  0.31985113] - 0.0
[0.37272096 0.30738777 0.3198912 ] - 0.0
[0.3726058  0.30745247 0.31994173] - 0.0
[0.37252814 0.30749673 0.31997514] - 0.0
[0.37248093 0.30752468 0.3199944 ] - 0.0
[0.37240618 0.3075688  0.320025  ] - 1.0
```

Something things that I have tried:

**Using weights:**

- Weights just made it predict 0 less, but the training did not
  improve, and the predictions were still the same constant spread.

**Predicting if the output will be 0:**

- Predicting if the output will be 0 resulted in the same probability
  like predictions.

I have a feeling that with the data I have available this is the most accurate way to make these predictions for the model.

**Are there any other solutions or is my hunch correct?**

My current neural network structure:

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(10, 2), activation="tanh"))
model1.add(Dropout(0.2))
model1.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, activation="tanh"))
model1.add(Dropout(0.2))
model1.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False, activation="tanh"))
model1.add(Dropout(0.2))
model1.add(Dense(32, activation="tanh"))
model1.add(Dropout(0.2))
model1.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model1.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.000001), loss=['sparse_categorical_crossentropy'])
```

Comment: What is the real problem? Are you saying the model is over-fit?

Comment: BTW, I know you want to use an ML model to predict the bottom of a curve, but there are more accurate and efficient ways of doing that.

Comment: My model is resorting to predicting 0 because the dataset contains a large number of 0s. It doesn't even try to predict 1 or 2 at all.

Comment: Then you need more training data, for the other classes. Without further context, I don't think this is an algorithm problem.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code to replicate the error along with the description of the dataset you are using and what model you have used for model prediction.